# number of bytes required to store a certain number of bits

Tags: c, byte, bit-manipulation

I have a function that takes as input a number of bits, and returns the number of bytes required to store those bits:

```
unsigned int get_number_of_bytes(unsigned int number_of_bits);
```

So, assuming 8 bits per byte:

- `number_of_bits` = 0 => function returns 0
- `number_of_bits` = 1 => function returns 1
- `number_of_bits` = 8 => function returns 1
- `number_of_bits` = 9 => function returns 2

A possible implementation would be:

```
unsigned int get_number_of_bytes(unsigned int number_of_bits)
{
    if (number_of_bits == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (number_of_bits - 1) / CHAR_BIT + 1;
}
```

(`CHAR_BIT` is usually equal to 8.)

How to code this function without an `if` (and without a `?:` operator)?

Comment: `(number_of_bits + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT`

Comment: remember CHAR_BIT is in <limits.h> - maybe a little too pedantic also, cause he asked the number of bytes, not chars. We could assume a byte is 8 bits, however C spec defines byte as an "addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment" (clause 3.6 of the C standard).

Comment: @makapuf OK, but CHAR_BIT vs. 8 was really not the point.

Comment: Ah yes, I just wanted to be pedantic for the sake of it. This was mostly tongue in cheek.

Comment: Was my question so stupid to deserve a down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned int get_number_of_bytes(unsigned int number_of_bits)
{
    return (number_of_bits + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT;
}
```

Comment: This does not work: for example, returns 0 on input = 1.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer states the answer without showing the thought process to get to it. The formula to find the number of bytes needed to represent n bits is

```
ceil((float) number_of_bits / (float) BITS_PER_BYTE)
```

Convert to floating point numbers to preserve precision. Divide the number of bits by the number of bits per byte (8) to get the number of bytes needed. You then ceil the result because you usually can't have a fraction of a byte.

However, to avoid the ceil function use the following formula taken from geeksforgeeks. Because we'd end up casting the result to an integer afterwards anyways, we can just use integer division.

```
(number_of_bits + BITS_PER_BYTE - 1) / BITS_PER_BYTE
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-ceil-ab-without-using-ceil-function/

Comment: Why cast to `int`? How does `(number_of_bits + BITS_PER_BYTE - 1) / BITS_PER_BYTE` correspond to the ceiling function version? Note that if `number_of_bits` and `BITS_PER_BYTE` are integer values, then `number_of_bits / BITS_PER_BYTE` is integer division in C, and the result is truncated, so `ceil(number_of_bits / BITS_PER_BYTE)` would not work here as C code in the first place. If you want to show "the thought process" you will need to expand on this.